# AFNetworking - How works cache time for requests and images?

Tags: ios, image, caching, request, afnetworking

I'm using the [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) framework for iOS.

1. **The cache is controlled by the HTTP response header?**

   - If yes, it is based on the headers '*Cache-Control*' and '*Expires*' for normal requests?
   - If not, how caching works?
2. **You can customize the cache time and fixed it in 1 day, regardless of the HTTP response headers?**
3. **If there is image cache, it is stored on disk or saved to memory?**
4. **The cache requests work when the device has no internet connection?**

   - The user makes a request but the device showed no internet connection and the request was suspended. You can ignore the same requests when the device returns to its internet connection?
5. **The only way my application would work offline using database or can be based on the system cache of this framework?**
6. **You can change the timeout of requests without having to customize a '*NSURLRequest*'?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The cache is controlled by the HTTP response header?

Yes; this is how NSURLCache decides whether and for how long to cache data.

> It is based on the headers 'Cache-Control' and 'Expires' for normal requests?

Yes, although notably it will sometimes ignore cache requests if the cache period is too short.  Unfortunately, this is not documented behavior.

> You can customize the cache time and fixed it in 1 day, regardless of the HTTP response headers?

For more control over caching, you can use SDURLCache: https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache  AFNetworking recommends this library in their FAQ.

> If there is image cache, it is stored on disk or saved to memory?

For general requests, this is configurable by the developer (see the NSURLCache documentation).

For UIImageView+AFNetworking, an NSCache is used in addition to NSURLCache, which provides memory caching.

> The cache requests work when the device has no internet connection?

Yes, but the cache can be invalidated at any time, so do not rely on this.

> The user makes a request but the device showed no internet connection and the request was suspended. You can ignore the same requests when the device returns to its internet connection? The only way my application would work offline using database or can be based on the system cache of this framework?

You can manually check for a cached response after you have your NSURLRequest:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [myHTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:parameters];
NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
if (cachedResponse)
{
    // Use response
}
```

> You can change the timeout of requests without having to customize a 'NSURLRequest'?

Not out of the box, but you can override the method that creates the NSMutableURLRequest in your subclass to change it for each one.  This method is `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:`.

Comment: Thanks, His answers were very clear!